# ArangoSearch: how to search without specifying the document field?

Tags: search, arangodb

I'm looking into ArangoSearch for the first time and it looks like a pretty good functionality.
However, in all the tutorials, despite having the ability to tell it to index all fields, one cannot do a 'blind' search across all fields of the document. Like when we look at the example below:

```
FOR d in myView SEARCH d.text IN ["quick", "brown"] RETURN d
```

I don't seem to have the ability to just search `d` entirely without specifying each individual field that I want to include in my search. Is that correct and if so, why is that and are there workarounds? I'm dealing with a lot of different collections with a lot of different fields that can contain a relevant term, it would be a shame if I'd have to tabulate all of them to make an expansive search.